# Copy site on same server?

Tags: database, language

I have a wordpress installation running in my root folder, and I want a copy in /en (including theme, posts and pages). I want a bilingual site and found the plugins too complicated for me - so I decided to simply run a duplicate in /en.

I've created the /en folder and download all the wp files from my original install - i've also copied the database.

Where do I go from now? Do I need to install wordpress again, or can I just move all the files to my new folder, make a new database based on the old one, and change the settings in wp-config?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes Patrick, you need to install `wordpress` again in that directory and add a new databases or just use the existing one just put in mind that u should not use the same `prefix` which you used in your root installation, and after that just pop any `en` or `english` link in your root site lining to that newly made english wordpress.

Comment: Thanks, I've installed Wordpress in my new folder now, but I'm not sure if I should "replace" the database with a copy of the original one, or just somehow copy the contents from it into the db of the new install?

Comment: that will be up to you, you can also do like `export` the sql file and then `import` in your new database.